# Trying to build a Excel Spreadsheet Password remover

Tags: python-3.x, excel, 7zip

First of all:

Im not a Programmer at all. Im a Sysadmin, can mostly read different types of Script or Programming Languages & and somewhat understand them. The reason why Im building this tool: Im sick of doing this type of work every week for Users that forget theyr passwords of theyr own Excel Lists.

I got mostly of the Tool finished. Used Python3 as Language + on a Windows System.
The only thing im currently struggeling with is, i have my wonderful modified *.xml files modified ( and when manually pushing it back into the xl\worksheets\ folder via 7-Zip it works like expected ) but don't seem to find a way to push the files back via python into the Excel Container.

Has anyone here any idea how I could do this?

I've already tried to push back the files via zipfile but this not seems to work cause of the structure of the excel file itself.

And the Commandline of 7Zip is no help either for me or I am just to dumb right now.

Any help appreciated ^^"

Current Code. Quick n Dirty:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import errno
import shutil
import zipfile
import re
from os.path import basename

def createFolder(foldername):

    try:
        #Create Directory
        os.mkdir(foldername)
        print("Directory " , foldername , "created! ")
    except FileExistsError:
        print("Directory" , foldername , "already exists!")

def repppydirs():
    # Get current workdir
    global repppyimport, repppytemp, repppyexport
    workindir = os.getcwd()
    repppyimport = workindir + '\\import'
    repppytemp = workindir + '\\temp'
    repppyexport = workindir + '\\export'

    createFolder(repppyimport)
    createFolder(repppytemp)
    createFolder(repppyexport)



# Replaces the Password String inside the XML Sheets
def findPasswordLine(inputSource,tempdir,filename):
    input = open(inputSource)
    output = open(tempdir + '\\' + filename,'w')
    for line in input:
        # REgex Helper ;) https://pythex.org/
        output.write(re.sub('<sheetProtection.*?.>', '', line))
    input.close()
    output.close()

def writeback2excel(zip_file,folder,file):
    z = zipfile.ZipInfo()
    z.filename = "xl\\worksheets"
    filedata = open()

def main(rimport,rtemp,rexport):

    listOfFile = os.listdir(rimport)
    #FileList = list()
    for file in listOfFile:
        print(file)
        # Copy file to work with
        src_dir = rimport + '\\' + file 
        dst_temp_dir = rtemp + '\\temp_' + file
        dst_exp_dir = rexport + '\\reppy_' + file
        shutil.copy(src_dir,dst_temp_dir)
        shutil.copy(src_dir,dst_exp_dir)
        with zipfile.ZipFile(dst_temp_dir,'r') as zip_ref:
            ziptmp = rtemp + '\\zip'
            createFolder(ziptmp)
            zip_ref.extractall(ziptmp)
            modxmlpath = ziptmp + '\\xl\\worksheets'
            modxmltree = os.listdir(modxmlpath)
            tempxl = rtemp + '\\xl'
            createFolder(tempxl)
            srtemp = tempxl + '\\worksheets'
            createFolder(srtemp)
            for mxml in modxmltree:
                if(mxml.endswith('.xml')):
                    print(mxml)
                    findPasswordLine(modxmlpath + '\\' + mxml,srtemp,mxml)
                    writeback2excel(dst_exp_dir,srtemp,mxml)   

    return

## Call to action 

repppydirs()
main(repppyimport,repppytemp,repppyexport)
```

Comment: Please add more detail and post your current code. I assume you are referring to converting an office file to a zip to manipulate via Python. Then you are trying to convert this modified zip into a excel file. Am I correct in this understanding?

Comment: Well the common practise to remove a the Password lock from an Excel Spreadsheet is to open it with 7zip. After you move to xl/worksheets extract the sheetX.xml files. Then you need to remove the Part with <sheetProtection ABCXD> from every sheetX.xml. After Removal you copy them back into to the xl/worksheet folder and tada, you can modify the cells again. So far everything works with the code exept I have no idea how i can push the sheetX.xml back into the Excel file.

Comment: I've done this before but with a different approach (so I cannot really help with this approach). My [approach](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/ms-office-tips/how-to-remove-crack-or-break-a-forgotten-excel-xls-password/) was through [brute-force decryption](https://exceloffthegrid.com/removing-cracking-excel-passwords-with-vba/). This has always worked for me and I picked an article from 2020 so it should still work. This method should be much simpler (only requires VBA, no 7z, Python, etc.). Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after tinkering around with the 7zip commandline I just found out its much easier than thought :)

For anyone else wanting to update an Excel file with its sheetX.xml files you need to do two things.

First you need to export the sheetX.xml files into a directoy structure of `'\xl\worksheets\'`

after this you can download the 7zip cmd line version and put everything into your python project together and use the Update function like shown below:

```
.\7za.exe u '..\export\yourexcelfile.xlsm' '..\folderAbovexl\*'
```

That will do the trick of writing everything back into the excel file.

If you just want to copy paste:

```
def writeback2excel(zip_file,workindir):
    # 7Zip Locations
    z7location = workindir + '\\7z\\7za.exe'
    # Export with 7z 
    os.system(f'{z7location} u "{zip_file}" "{workindir}\\temp\\export\\*" ')
```

And do some adjustments in my Question Post and you have a python based excel spreadsheet password remover.

Have a good one :)

EDIT: Postet on github https://github.com/pabumake/reppy